# Find the distribution of $X|Y=y$ where X and Y look like a a bivariate poisson.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, self-learning

It isn't a bivariate Poisson precisely, but has a pmf of:

$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x, Y=y)=\frac{\lambda^y e^{-2 \lambda}}{x !(y-x) !} I_{\{0, \ldots, y\}}(x) I_{\mathbb{N}}(y), \lambda>0$$

When I tried to evaluate $\mathbb{P}(Y=y) $ I ended up reaching a sum I don't know how to handle:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(y=y) & =\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(x=i, y=y) \\
& =\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^y e^{-2 \lambda}}{i !(y-i) !} I_{\{0, \ldots, y\}}(i) I_{\mathbb{N}}(y) \\
& =x^y e^{-2 \lambda} I_{\mathbb{N}}(y) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i !(y-i) !} I_{\{0, \ldots, y\}}(i) \\
& =\lambda^y e^{-2 \lambda} I_{\mathbb{N}}(y) \sum_{i=0}^y \frac{1}{i !(y-i) !}
\end{aligned}
$$

Am I going in the right direction? Or is there another argument I could be thinking about?

Comment: $Y$ looks like the sum of $X$ and $Z$ where $Z$ is i.i.d. with $X$ as Poisson with parameter $\lambda$.  So given $Y=y$ this looks like splitting $Y$  between $X$ and $Z$ and it would not surprise me if each had a conditional  binomial distribution with parameters $y$ and $\frac12$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there. Here is how to calculate the sum:
\begin{align*}
       \sum_{i = 0}^y \dfrac{1}{i!(y - i)!} &= \dfrac{1}{y!}\sum_{i = 0}^y \dfrac{y!}{i!(y-i)!}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{y!}\sum_{i = 0}^y C^i_y
\end{align*}
Recall the Newton's binomial theorem,
$$
     (a + b)^y = \sum_{i = 0}^y C^i_y a^i b^{y - i}
$$
By choosing $a = b = 1$, we have
$$
      \sum_{i = 0}^y C_y^i = 2^y
$$
Thus,
$$
    \mathbb{P}(Y = y) = e^{-2\lambda} \dfrac{(2\lambda)^y}{y!}1_{\mathbb{N}}(y)
$$
or, $Y \sim \mathcal{P}(2\lambda)$